# How to solve the Alamofire to display the data

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have the URL to display the data and it is working in the urlsession. But I need Alamofire so I have done it in the Alamofire. But in that it is showing as:

> Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(404)

How to fix the problem?

This is the code in the Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request("http://www.example.com").validate(statusCode: 200..<300).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON{ response in
    let status = response.response?.statusCode
    print("STATUS \(status)")
    print(response)

    switch response.result {
    case .success(let data):
        print("success",data)

        let result = response.result

        print(result)

        if  let wholedata = result.value as? [String:Any]{
            print(wholedata)

            if  let data = wholedata["data"] as? Array<[String:Any]>{
                print(data)
                print(response)

                for question in data {
                    let typebutton = question["button_type"] as? String
                    print(typebutton)
                    self.type = typebutton

                    let options = question["options"] as! [String]

                    //   self.dataListArray1 = [options]
                    self.tableArray.append(options)
                    // self.savedataforoptions(completion: <#T##(NH_OptionslistDataSourceModel?) -> ()#>)

                    self.no = options.count
                }

                print(self.tableArray)

                let newDataSource:QuestionDataSourceModel = QuestionDataSourceModel(array: data)

                completion(newDataSource)
            }
        }
    case .failure(let encodingError ):
        print(encodingError)

        //  if response.response?.statusCode == 404{
        print(encodingError.localizedDescription)

        completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 404 is for not found make sure you are passing url and parameter correctly

Comment: Looks like request sent through Alamofire is not valid.

Comment: i got the output by changing in the podfile

Comment: i used Alamofire -4.4.0 version